# Find specific text through pandas

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I was trying to find a way to

**Done**! **1st step)** possibly count all occurences of a certain text (e.g "神", or "仏教") in one json or csv

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10000

# read file
df = pd.read_csv("/mypath/results.csv")
# add search parameters 
df['text_of_interest_status']=df['text'].str.count('神')
df=df[df['text_of_interest_status']==1]
# print search parameters
df['text'].str.count('神')
```

(and if possible)

**Open: 2nd step)** create a new file (json or csv) of all rows with occurences and save that.

my csv file is this: [csvfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ooSy0grRjioSD7V844R3_EM7HjPDs056/view?usp=sharing)

2)
As for the second step I am not sure how to set it up, so that the rows containing the text, would be gathered.
I guess the final part would be somewhat like this?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

# <some magic inbetween>

# print(new_df)
new_df.to_csv("/myfilepath/mynewfile.csv")
```

・・・

**Edit:** (07/18)

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a Dataframe to `pd.Series` function.

Do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/myfilepath/myfile.csv")
df['text_of_interest_status']=df['text'].str.count('神')

df['text'].str.count('神')
Out[4]: 
0     1
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     1
10    0
11    0
Name: text, dtype: int64
```

**EDIT:**

if you want to filter only the rows having the text of interest, you can just do this:

```
df=df[df['text_of_interest_status']==1]
```